# Rewrite url only for a specific id

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this URL`content.php?type=4` and value for type is changing all the time.
What should I write in htaccess file in order to have this URL: `content/flower`

The important part is I only need it for `type=4`, so if the type=5 or type=6, I don't bother.

As result by typing `content/flower` in url, apache should look for `content.php?type=4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RewriteRule` to redirect to the new URL.

```
RewriteRule ^content/flower$ /content.php?type=4 [NC]
```

Therefore, the URL `content/flower` redirects the request to `content.php?type=4` without the client knowing.

You can then edit this `.htaccess` file to `type=5` or `type=6` with the same public URL being shared and used.

EDIT:
Your question was unclear as to what redirects to what, so I've update this answer to reflect the last line if your question.

Comment: It doesn't work.... I don't know why. I searched all over the internet and I found the exact solution which you said.... But still :(

Comment: What does Apache error log say? Do you have `Options +FollowSymLinks` and `RewriteEngine On` above this; I've assumed you do.

Comment: It is like it does not find the content. so it goes to error page

Comment: Also, to make it clear, I want to have a clear and SEO friendly url only when type=4

Answer (score 0):

> RewriteRule ^content/flower$ /content.php?type=4 [NC]

Edit: I agree with the first solution

Comment: This won't work as the poster wants a URL of `content/flower` to go to `content.php?type=4`; you've done the opposite.

Comment: It doesn't work.... I don't know why. I searched all over the internet and I found the exact solution which you said.... But still :(

Comment: I agree with Egg now.

RewriteRule ^content/flower$ /content.php?type=4 [NC]